# How much human-provided power is needed on an e-bike?

Tags: electric-bike, electric-power, theoretical

If we want to ride 50 miles (80 km) on a 35lb (15.9kg) Class 2 e-bike at an average speed of 20mph (32 km/h), how much power does the human need to provide if e-bike is on light-assist setting?

Comment: what the "light assist" setting means varies widely between different e-bike systems.  need to be more specific.

Comment: Juhist's answer is basically correct. To you it might be more useful to say how much power you need to provide to sustain the maximum allowed assisted speed of 20 mph on a flat section. However, no-one can know without detailed knowledge of your bike and your aerodynamics.

Answer (score 6):

In order to ride at an average speed of 20 mph, especially when riding on the light setting you can't go at 20 mph on uphills. This means you need to go much faster than 20 mph on the flats. Let's say 22 mph on the flats would be enough. That's a whopping 35.4 km/h. Even on a road bike riding position (CdA 0.45 square meters) and using fragile low rolling resistance narrow high pressure road tires (crr 0.003), it would require 283 watts of power to do that. Exactly zero percent of that is provided by the motor as the assist of this type of e-bike stops at 20 mph. So 100% needs to be provided by you. Besides, very small percentage of e-bikes are road bikes. Thus the riding position and rolling resistance best case I used is probably not realistic.

If the bike is legal, you won't be averaging 20 mph. 283 watts is a huge amount of power. And on a more typical riding position (not road bike, CdA 0.55 square meters) and more typical tires (not fragile narrow high pressure slicks, crr 0.007) it's something like 373 watts.

Comment: Just some notes for the OP in case they aren't familiar with cycling technical terms. CdA is coefficient of aerodynamic drag * frontal area. It measures what it sounds like; the power required to overcome aerodynamic resistance increases with the *cube* of your velocity. CRR is coefficient of rolling resistance, which measures your tires' rolling resistance. The Continental Grand Prix 5000 is a road racing tire (not racing-only) with a CRR of 0.003. I dispute that it's generally fragile, but it will be fragile in an e-bike context.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how much the “light assist” setting actually assists.

To ride 32km/h (20mph) on flat terrain with a road bike in road bike clothes you need about 170W to 210W. With a city-bike or mountain-bike and baggy clothing it’s much more.

I think most eBikes have – depending on jurisdiction – at least 250W of motor power, so physically the motor would be able to do all the work. It really depends on how this assist level is implemented and if the motor, motor controller and battery can sustain this power output for more than 2 hours.

You’d need a power meter (e.g. pedal based) to run experiments and see how much power the human has to provide for this kind of speed.

Answer (score 2):

Cycling power is frequently measured is in watts.
To know how much power the rider needs to contribute to a 20 mph speed over 50 miles you need to know:

- How much power is needed to sustain 20 miles per hour for 50 miles under the conditions (wind, hills, elevation, etc.)
- Subtract the power contributed by the electric motor
- What's left is the amount of power the rider would have to contribute.

> One Watt corresponds to one Joule of energy produced every second.
> ["Cycling Wattage Calculator"](https://www.omnicalculator.com/sports/cycling-wattage)

**How much power is needed to sustain 20 mph for 50 miles?**
The short answer is - we can't say exactly based on the information in the question.

To demonstrate how the answer might be found we can look at an idealized case.
According to the [Bike Calculator](http://www.bikecalculator.com/examples.html) it takes 317 watts to sustain 20 miles per hour - with no electronic assist - assuming:
[image]

This is an idealized un-assisted estimated measurement.

If you rode 50 miles at 20 mph it would take you 2 hours and 30 minutes.
For some perspective, sustaining 317 watts (317 is with no hills) for 1 hour would put you in the top 17% of male athletes:

> - 82.7% of people have an FTP below 310W.
> - 13.3% of people have an FTP of 320W or more.
> - 4% of people have an FTP between 310W and 320W

[Cyclinganalytics.com](https://www.cyclinganalytics.com/blog/2018/06/how-does-your-cycling-power-output-compare)

**How much power will the e-bike contribute to the ride?**
The e-bike manufacturer will need to provide you with a number in watts the bike can sustain for 2.5 hours.
According to [Bike Radar](https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/electric-bike-faqs/)

> Watt hours (or Wh) refers to the energy capacity of your bike’s battery and provides an indication as to its likely range.
> A battery’s Wh will also show how many watts it is able to continuously provide for an hour: for example, a 250Wh battery can provide 250 watts of assistance for one hour, 125 watts for two hours, and so on.

Keep in mind that:

> Generally speaking, the higher the wattage, the higher your electric bicycle power will be. However, many ebikes are labeled differently than their actual power level, whether it be for marketing gimmicks, to sneak higher powered ebikes past laws and regulations, or a whole host of other reasons.
> [ebikeschool.com](http://www.ebikeschool.com/much-power-electric-bicycle-need/#:%7E:text=Power%20requirements%20go%20up%20quickly%20for%20folks%20weighing,a%201%2C000%20watt%20ebike%20would%20be%20the%20minimum.)

**How much power will the rider need to provide?**
[Needed power] minus [electric power] = [needed rider power]

Just for fun let's "what if" a little.
What if you put in all the most accurate numbers and find that with hills, wind, etc. you are at:

- **600** watts for 2.5 hours to do 20 mph for 50 miles.
  If you have a bike with a 500 Wh battery then
- 500/2.5 hours = **200** watts of electric power.
- **600** - **200** = 400 watts of human needed power, way more than the best riders can sustain for 2.5 hours.

If you have a bike with a 1000 Wh battery then you get 400 watts of electric power and the rider contribution drops to 200, a number some riders can attain.

Comment: The statistics for cyclinganalysis are not statistic for male riders. They are statistics for male ATHLETES. That's different from the entire riding population.

Comment: @juhist Thanks, I corrected my wording - the statistics from cyclinganalysis are a quote. The word they use use "people"

Comment: The capability of the electric motor to actually provide a given amount of help at a given speed is also highly dependent on the specific ebike technology.  A cheap basic hub motor simply cannot provide say only 50w of help when you're doing 20mph because you want to extend the battery and get a small amount of help, because it just doesn't have the gearing to do so.

Comment: The last bit makes a pretty big jump from the estimated 317W to an arbitrary 600W - nearly double.  If you stuck with your 317W, you'd only need to put in 117W, which is a fairly easy all day pace for a reasonably fit man (less than Strava reckons I can sustain for 200 miles).  The truth will be somewhere in between, unfortunately that means somewhere in between "yes" and "no".